# Reading a File line by line

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I'm working on the creation of an Android App to track financial expenses and I would like to allow the user to batch import financial transactions into my app. The transactions would be come as .csv/.txt files.

However, I'm getting a cryptic exception:

> ```
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.content.IContentProvider  android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)"
> at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1780)
>    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1394)
>    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
>    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:967)
>  ....
> ```

Workflow is as follow: User selects text file to import, App imports content.

Start the file selector:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
//intent.addCategory("CATEGORY_OPENABLE");

startActivityForResult(intent, REEQUEST_CODE_IMPORT);
```

Catch the result:

```java
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REEQUEST_CODE_IMPORT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            Uri path = data.getData();

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && path != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = new ContentResolver(getContext()) {};

                    // Error happens in the next line
                    inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(path);

                    // Get the object of DataInputStream
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Do something meaningful... 
                    }

                } catch () {
                    // Catch the exceptions ( I have removed some boiler plate code here...)
                } finally {
                    // Close the path ( I have removed some boiler plate code here...) 
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If Java 8 is an option, try `Files::readAllLines` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: Not sure why you are using `contentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor` as this is for Uri's that start with `android.resource:` to load files from the APK . I'm not sure this is causing the error but this is not the type of URI you will get back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` use `contentResolver.openInputStream` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android documentation helped me solve the issue: [Access documents and other files from shared storage - Input Stream](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#input_stream)

Following code adaptation is working:

```java
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REEQUEST_CODE_IMPORT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            Uri path = data.getData();

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && path != null) {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    try (InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
                         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, line);
                            stringBuilder.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String content = stringBuilder.toString();
                    // Do something with it
            }
        }
    }
```